# Matrix multiplication, solve Ax = b solve for x

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

So I was given a homework assignment that requires solving the coefficients of cubic splines. Now I clearly understand how to do the math on paper as well as with MatLab, I want to solve the problem with Python. Given an equation Ax = b where I know the values of A and b, I want to be able to solve for x with Python and I am having trouble finding a good resource to do such a thing.

Ex.

```
A = |1 0 0|
    |1 4 1|
    |0 0 1|

x = Unknown 3x1 matrix

b = |0 |
    |24| 
    |0 |
```

Solve for x

Comment: @MattDMo: OP already tagged `numpy`.

Comment: I have looked at NumPy a little but its a lot to get through, do you know which NumPy function(s), or at least which area of NumPy would handle this best?

Comment: If `Ax = B`, `x = (A^-1)B`. Take a look at `inv` and `dot` functions.

Comment: @Amadan - true, didn't see that...

Comment: as a general reference, take a look at the [NumPy for Matlab Users page](http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users) if you haven't come across it already. Scrolling down, there's a big list of linear algebra equivalents that may be helpful, as well as a variety of other comparisons to help you from Matlab to the exciting world of Python :)

Comment: @Amadan, that was a big help. Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Extra marks for disclosing this is a homework assignment. That lets us treat it accordingly, giving you the benefit of the work you have to do to understand the solutions.

Comment: Solving linear equations by calculating the inverse like @Amadan suggested is a nice way to write the solution mathematically but it should be avoided for real code as there are far better algorithms for it.

Comment: @holdenweb Only extra marks for disclosing that it's a homework assignment if it actually is. ;-) (I came here to learn Python as a teacher.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In a general case, use `solve`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy.linalg import solve
>>> 
>>> A = np.random.random((3, 3))
>>> b = np.random.random(3)
>>> 
>>> x = solve(A, b)
>>> x
array([ 0.98323512,  0.0205734 ,  0.06424613])
>>> 
>>> np.dot(A, x) - b
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])
```

If your problem is banded (which cubic splines it often is), then there's http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solve_banded.html

To comment on some of the comments to the question: better *not* use `inv` for solving linear systems. `numpy.lstsq` is a bit different, it's more useful for fitting.

As this is homework, you're really better off at least reading up on ways of solving tridiagonal linear systems.

Answer (score 8):

Numpy is the main package for scientific computing in Python. If you are windows user then download it here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy else follow these instructions: http://www.scipy.org/install.html.

```
import numpy
A = [[1,0,0],[1,4,1],[0,0,1]]
b = [0,24,0]
x = numpy.linalg.lstsq(A,b)
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the code of Zhenya, you might also find it intuitive to use the np.dot function:

```
import numpy as np
A = [[1,0,0],
    [1,1,1],
    [6,7,0]]
b = [0,24,0]
# Now simply solve for x
x = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(A), b) 
#np.linalg.inv(A)  is simply the inverse of A, np.dot is the dot product
print x

Out[27]: array([  0.,   0.,  24.])
```